# How to get rid of nested loops

Tags: c, for-loop, recursion, nested-loops

I have a set of vessels (data is given in external .txt file: vessel number, arriving time, service time, due time, penalty factor, waiting factor) which come to the berth and served one by one. I need to find the order of vessels with the least cost. I am using very basic approach - I generate all possible sequences and than I compare a cost for each. A vessel can be served only once, which means there can be no repetitions in the sequence.
The cost of each newcoming vessel consists of waiting cost (the time it spent waiting in line) and penalty cost (the time it spent in berth after the due time).
Currently, I have a program with 10 nested loops for the set of 10 vessels.
The code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>



void main()
{

FILE *f1;
int n = 10;/*The number of vessels*/
int arr[10];
int count = 0, s = 1;
int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j;
int t[10];
int min;
int time[10];


struct vessel{
    int name;/*the name of the vessel*/
    int ar; /*arrival time*/
    int ser; /*service time*/
    int exp; /*due time*/
    int df; /*delay factor*/
    int wf; /*waiting factor*/
};
struct vessel x[10]; /* where number means the total number of vessels arriving*/

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    s = s*(n-i) ;
}
printf("S is %d\n", s);/*The number of possible sequences. (n-1)! */


f1 = fopen("sample1.txt", "r");/*Read data from file*/
if (f1 == NULL){
    printf("Can not open the file\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    fscanf(f1, "%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", &x[i].name, &x[i].ar, &x[i].ser, &x[i].exp, &x[i].df, &x[i].wf);
    arr[i] = x[i].name;
}


/*f2 = fopen("results.txt", "w");*/

min = 9999999999;/*Set it to be big.*/

for (a = 0; a < n; a++)/*First step. Set time and cost.*/
{
    t[a] = 0;/*As first vessel comes and goes, there are no penalt or waiting cost.*/
    time[a] = x[a].ar + x[a].ser;/*The time vessel arrives + the service time.*/
    for (b = 0; b < n; b++)/*LOOP START.*/
    {
        if (b != a)/*One vessel can be served only once.*/
        {
            time[b] = 0;
            if (time[a] > x[b].ar)/*If vessel arrived during service time of the previous one*/
            {
                if ((time[a] + x[b].ser - x[b].exp) > 0)/*If the service of current vessel ends after the due time.*/
                {
                    t[b] = t[a] + (time[a] - x[b].ar)*x[b].wf + (time[a] + x[b].ser - x[b].exp)*x[b].df;
                }
                else/*If the service ends before the due time.*/
                {
                    t[b] = t[a] + (time[a] - x[b].ar)*x[b].wf;
                }
                time[b] = time[a] + x[b].ser;/*Update time. The time when the service of current vessel ends.*/
            }
            else/*If vessel arrives after the service time of the previous one.*/
            {
                t[b] = t[a] + 0;/*No penalty or waiting cost.*/
                time[b] = x[b].ar + x[b].ser;/*Update time. Current vessel arrival time + its service time.*/
            }
            if (t[b] < min)/*Check if current cost is smaller than found minimum cost. If yes, continue. If not, go to the start of the loop. LOOP END.*/
            {
                for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
                {
                    if (c != b && c != a)
                    {
                        time[c] = 0;
                        if (time[b] > x[c].ar)
                        {
                            if ((time[b] + x[c].ser - x[c].exp) > 0)
                            {
                                t[c] = t[b] + (time[b] - x[c].ar)*x[c].wf + (time[b] + x[c].ser - x[c].exp)*x[c].df;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                t[c] = t[b] + (time[b] - x[c].ar)*x[c].wf;
                            }
                            time[c] = time[b] + x[c].ser;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            t[c] = t[b] + 0;
                            time[c] = x[c].ar + x[c].ser;
                        }
                        if (t[c] < min)
                        {
                            for (d = 0; d < n; d++)
                            {
                                if (d != c && d != b && d != a)
                                {
                                    time[d] = 0;
                                    if (time[c] > x[d].ar)
                                    {
                                        if ((time[c] + x[d].ser - x[d].exp) > 0)
                                        {
                                            t[d] = t[c] + (time[c] - x[d].ar)*x[d].wf + (time[c] + x[d].ser - x[d].exp)*x[d].df;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            t[d] = t[c] + (time[c] - x[d].ar)*x[d].wf;
                                        }
                                        time[d] = time[c] + x[d].ser;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        t[d] = t[c] + 0;
                                        time[d] = x[d].ar + x[d].ser;
                                    }
                                    if (t[d] < min)
                                    {
                                        for (e = 0; e < n; e++)
                                        {
                                            if (e != d && e != c && e != b && e != a)
                                            {
                                                time[e] = 0;
                                                if (time[d] > x[e].ar)
                                                {
                                                    if ((time[d] + x[e].ser - x[e].exp) > 0)
                                                    {
                                                        t[e] = t[d] + (time[d] - x[e].ar)*x[e].wf + (time[d] + x[e].ser - x[e].exp)*x[e].df;
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        t[e] = t[d] + (time[d] - x[e].ar)*x[e].wf;
                                                    }
                                                    time[e] = time[d] + x[e].ser;
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    t[e] = t[d] + 0;
                                                    time[e] = x[e].ar + x[e].ser;
                                                }
                                                if (t[e] < min)
                                                {
                                                    for (f = 0; f < n; f++)
                                                    {
                                                        if (f != e && f != d && f != c && f != b && f != a)
                                                        {
                                                            time[f] = 0;
                                                            if (time[e] > x[f].ar)
                                                            {
                                                                if ((time[e] + x[f].ser - x[f].exp) > 0)
                                                                {
                                                                    t[f] = t[e] + (time[e] - x[f].ar)*x[f].wf + (time[e] + x[f].ser - x[f].exp)*x[f].df;
                                                                }
                                                                else
                                                                {
                                                                    t[f] = t[e] + (time[e] - x[f].ar)*x[f].wf;
                                                                }
                                                                time[f] = time[e] + x[f].ser;
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                t[f] = t[e] + 0;
                                                                time[f] = x[f].ar + x[f].ser;
                                                            }
                                                            if (t[f] < min)
                                                            {
                                                                for (g = 0; g < n; g++)
                                                                {
                                                                    if (g != a && g != b && g != c && g != d && g != e && g != f)
                                                                    {

                                                                        time[g] = 0;
                                                                        if (time[f] > x[g].ar)
                                                                        {
                                                                            if ((time[f] + x[g].ser - x[g].exp) > 0)
                                                                            {
                                                                                t[g] = t[f] + (time[f] - x[g].ar)*x[g].wf + (time[f] + x[g].ser - x[g].exp)*x[g].df;
                                                                            }
                                                                            else
                                                                            {
                                                                                t[g] = t[f] + (time[f] - x[g].ar)*x[g].wf;
                                                                            }
                                                                            time[g] = time[f] + x[g].ser;
                                                                        }
                                                                        else
                                                                        {
                                                                            t[g] = t[f] + 0;
                                                                            time[g] = x[g].ar + x[g].ser;
                                                                        }
                                                                        if (t[g] < min)
                                                                        {
                                                                            for (h = 0; h < n; h++)
                                                                            {
                                                                                if (h != a && h != b && h != c && h != d && h != e && h != f && h != g)
                                                                                {
                                                                                    time[h] = 0;
                                                                                    if (time[g] > x[h].ar)
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        if ((time[g] + x[h].ser - x[h].exp) > 0)
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            t[h] = t[g] + (time[g] - x[h].ar)*x[h].wf + (time[g] + x[h].ser - x[h].exp)*x[h].df;
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        else
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            t[h] = t[g] + (time[g] - x[h].ar)*x[h].wf;
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        time[h] = time[g] + x[h].ser;
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    else
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        t[h] = t[g] + 0;
                                                                                        time[h] = x[h].ar + x[h].ser;
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    if (t[h] < min)
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            if (i != a && i != b && i != c && i != d && i != e && i != f && i != g && i != h)
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                time[i] = 0;
                                                                                                if (time[h] > x[i].ar)
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                    if ((time[h] + x[i].ser - x[i].exp) > 0)
                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                        t[i] = t[h] + (time[h] - x[i].ar)*x[i].wf + (time[h] + x[i].ser - x[i].exp)*x[i].df;
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                    else
                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                        t[i] = t[h] + (time[h] - x[i].ar)*x[i].wf;
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                    time[i] = time[h] + x[i].ser;
                                                                                                }
                                                                                                else
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                    t[i] = t[h] + 0;
                                                                                                    time[i] = x[i].ar + x[i].ser;
                                                                                                }
                                                                                                if (t[i] < min)
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                        if (j != a && j != b && j != c && j != d && j != e && j != f && j != g && j != h && j != i)
                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                            time[j] = 0;
                                                                                                            if (time[i] > x[j].ar)
                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                if ((time[i] + x[j].ser - x[j].exp) > 0)
                                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                    t[j] = t[i] + (time[i] - x[j].ar)*x[j].wf + (time[i] + x[j].ser - x[j].exp)*x[j].df;
                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                else
                                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                    t[j] = t[i] + (time[i] - x[j].ar)*x[j].wf;
                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                time[j] = time[i] + x[j].ser;
                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                            else
                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                t[j] = t[i] + 0;
                                                                                                                time[j] = x[j].ar + x[j].ser;
                                                                                                            }


                                                                                                            if (t[j] < min)
                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                min = t[j];
                                                                                                                printf("%d\n", min);
                                                                                                                /*printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", t[a], t[b], t[c], t[d], t[e], t[f], t[g], t[h], t[i], t[j]);*/
                                                                                                                arr[0] = a + 1; arr[1] = b + 1; arr[2] = c + 1; arr[3] = d + 1; arr[4] = e + 1; arr[5] = f + 1; arr[6] = g + 1; arr[7] = h + 1; arr[8] = i + 1; arr[9] = j + 1;
                                                                                                            }

                                                                                                            count++;/*How many sequences of n vessels were able to reach the end of loop.*/

                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

printf("Final sequence is: ");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
}
printf("\nFinal count is %d\n", count);
printf("Final cost is %d\n", min);


getch();
return 0;
}
```

This code works. BUT.
It is long and nasty. I have no idea how to change it.
The only part that matter for me are loops.
The sample data (just in case)

```
1, 756, 207, 1148, 1160, 303
2, 660, 243, 1105, 847, 344
3, 1444, 225, 1857, 1006, 310
4, 1554, 199, 1941, 1004, 326
5, 1376, 186, 1737, 1112, 321
6, 1396, 170, 1680, 1053, 247
7, 1577, 158, 1917, 1005, 275
8, 629, 218, 1026, 976, 289
9, 807, 181, 1151, 1078, 299
10, 779, 157, 1088, 804, 254
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Two thoughts, one, why not paste a compilable version? Two, does it work correctly now?

Comment: Better description of problem is needed here. I'm beyond certain it can be solved without 10 loops.

Comment: Made some changes in description. Tell me if i need to clarify smth else.

Comment: If you want to make a sequence that contains every combination of vessels, wouldn't recursion be a better choice so that you have back tracking?  I might have a try...

Comment: I am thinking about recursion as my first option. But i don't know how it works.

Comment: Is this a real-life problem or a toy problem for learning?

Comment: Toy problem. I guess, it can be simplified real-life problem, but not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other commenters have already pointed out, recursion is a good solution to the problem. I've coded a working solution, see below. I've packed the current and (current) optimum orders of the ships into the `vessel` struct. The original solution used a separate array.

The `order` entry also serves as an indicator whether a ship has been serviced or not. Zero means it is in the waiting queue or has not yet arrived, a positive number represents the ship's order. This value is set before recursing deeper and reset afterwards.

In the recursive function, `n` is the (constant) number of vessels, `m` is the number of vessels that have been serviced. This allows for a quick check whether we're done. Otherwise, `m` would have to be determined with an additional loop at the beginning of `service`.

The current minimum is passed to the recursive function via pointer. A global variable would also have worked, but I think the "closed" solution where everything is local to `service` is cleaner.

This solution is extensible to more than 10 vessels. (I get the same order as you, but the cost is different, so my solution has an error in calculating the cost. I'll leave that as an exercise, *yadda, yadda...* In principle, the code seems to work, though.)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>



typedef struct Vessel Vessel;

struct Vessel {
    int id;
    int arrival;
    int service;
    int due;
    int delay_cost;
    int waiting_cost;
    int order;          /* Current order, 0 means not yet treated */
    int final;          /* final (optimum) order */
};

void service(Vessel *vessel, int n, int m, int time, int cost, int *min)
{
    int i;

    if (cost > *min) return;

    if (m == n) {
        while (n--) vessel[n].final = vessel[n].order;
        *min = cost;
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Vessel *v = vessel + i;
        int dtime = v->service;
        int dcost = 0;

        if (v->order) continue;

        if (m == 0) {
            time = v->arrival;
        } else {
            if (time < v->arrival) {
                dtime += v->arrival - time;
                dcost += (v->arrival - time) * v->waiting_cost;
            }
        }

        if (time + dtime > v->due) {
            dcost += v->delay_cost * (time + dtime - v->due);
        }

        v->order = m + 1;
        service(vessel, n, m + 1, time + dtime, cost + dcost, min);
        v->order = 0;
    }
}

int vessel_cmp(const void *aa, const void *bb)
{
    const Vessel *a = aa;
    const Vessel *b = bb;

    return a->final - b->final;
}

int main()
{
    Vessel vessel[] = {
        {1,  756, 207, 1148, 1160, 303, 0, 0},
        {2,  660, 243, 1105,  847, 344, 0, 0},
        {3, 1444, 225, 1857, 1006, 310, 0, 0},
        {4, 1554, 199, 1941, 1004, 326, 0, 0},
        {5, 1376, 186, 1737, 1112, 321, 0, 0},
        {6, 1396, 170, 1680, 1053, 247, 0, 0},
        {7, 1577, 158, 1917, 1005, 275, 0, 0},
        {8,  629, 218, 1026,  976, 289, 0, 0},
        {9,  807, 181, 1151, 1078, 299, 0, 0},
        {10, 779, 157, 1088,  804, 254, 0, 0},
    };
    int nvessel = 10;
    int min = 0x7fffffff;
    int i;

    service(vessel, nvessel, 0, 0, 0, &min);
    qsort(vessel, nvessel, sizeof(vessel[0]), vessel_cmp);

    printf("Final order: ");
    for (i = 0; i < nvessel; i++) {
        if (i) printf(", ");
        printf("%d", vessel[i].id);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Total cost: %d\n", min);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly I was looking for. Simple and elegant. You are amazing.

Comment: Ok, there is a tradeoff. Bigger the number of vessels, more time it takes to count. And time grows up exponentially. So, for the set of 10 it will take like 10 secs, for the set of 14 - 450 secs.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor into smaller function and then go back an refactor any common logic into on function.

Start from the inner most nesting and work your way out. I would go with the rule of thumb here keep each function to a maximum of 3 nested conditions.

Edit: I notice a lot of common logic which could be handled with recursive calls and restructuring a-j variables in an array which you pass along in your recursive function.

Example (please note this pseudo code):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>

void functionA(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, *t, *time, *min, *arr, *count) {
    if (j != a && j != b && j != c && j != d && j != e && j != f && j != g && j != h && j != i)
    {
        time[j] = 0;
        if (time[i] > x[j].ar)
        {
            if ((time[i] + x[j].ser - x[j].exp) > 0)
            {
                t[j] = t[i] + (time[i] - x[j].ar)*x[j].wf + (time[i] + x[j].ser - x[j].exp)*x[j].df;
            }
            else
            {
                t[j] = t[i] + (time[i] - x[j].ar)*x[j].wf;
            }
            time[j] = time[i] + x[j].ser;
        }
        else
        {
            t[j] = t[i] + 0;
            time[j] = x[j].ar + x[j].ser;
        }


        if (t[j] < min)
        {
            min = t[j];
            printf("%d\n", min);
            /*printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", t[a], t[b], t[c], t[d], t[e], t[f], t[g], t[h], t[i], t[j]);*/

            // NOTE YOU CAN WRITE A LOOP HERE
            arr[0] = a + 1;
            arr[1] = b + 1; 
            arr[2] = c + 1; 
            arr[3] = d + 1;
            arr[4] = e + 1; 
            arr[5] = f + 1;
            arr[6] = g + 1;
            arr[7] = h + 1;
            arr[8] = i + 1;
            arr[9] = j + 1;
        }

        count++;/*How many sequences of n vessels were able to reach the end of loop.*/
    }
}

void functionB(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, *t, *time, *min, *arr, *count) {
    if (i != a && i != b && i != c && i != d && i != e && i != f && i != g && i != h)
    {
        time[i] = 0;
        if (time[h] > x[i].ar)
        {
            if ((time[h] + x[i].ser - x[i].exp) > 0)
            {
                t[i] = t[h] + (time[h] - x[i].ar)*x[i].wf + (time[h] + x[i].ser - x[i].exp)*x[i].df;
            }
            else
            {
                t[i] = t[h] + (time[h] - x[i].ar)*x[i].wf;
            }
            time[i] = time[h] + x[i].ser;
        }
        else
        {
            t[i] = t[h] + 0;
            time[i] = x[i].ar + x[i].ser;
        }
        if (t[i] < min)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                functionA(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, t, time, min, arr, count);
            }
        }
    }
}

void functionC(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, *t, *time, *min, *arr, *count) {
    if (h != a && h != b && h != c && h != d && h != e && h != f && h != g)
    {
        time[h] = 0;
        if (time[g] > x[h].ar)
        {
            if ((time[g] + x[h].ser - x[h].exp) > 0)
            {
                t[h] = t[g] + (time[g] - x[h].ar)*x[h].wf + (time[g] + x[h].ser - x[h].exp)*x[h].df;
            }
            else
            {
                t[h] = t[g] + (time[g] - x[h].ar)*x[h].wf;
            }
            time[h] = time[g] + x[h].ser;
        }
        else
        {
            t[h] = t[g] + 0;
            time[h] = x[h].ar + x[h].ser;
        }
        if (t[h] < min)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                functionB(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, t, time, min, arr, count);
            }
        }
    }
}

void functionD(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, *t, *time, *min, *arr, *count) {
    if (g != a && g != b && g != c && g != d && g != e && g != f)
    {

        time[g] = 0;
        if (time[f] > x[g].ar)
        {
            if ((time[f] + x[g].ser - x[g].exp) > 0)
            {
                t[g] = t[f] + (time[f] - x[g].ar)*x[g].wf + (time[f] + x[g].ser - x[g].exp)*x[g].df;
            }
            else
            {
                t[g] = t[f] + (time[f] - x[g].ar)*x[g].wf;
            }
            time[g] = time[f] + x[g].ser;
        }
        else
        {
            t[g] = t[f] + 0;
            time[g] = x[g].ar + x[g].ser;
        }
        if (t[g] < min)
        {
            for (h = 0; h < n; h++)
            {
                functionC(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, t, time, min, arr, count);
            }
        }
    }
}

void functionE(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, *t, *time, *min, *arr, *count) {
    if (f != e && f != d && f != c && f != b && f != a)
    {
        time[f] = 0;
        if (time[e] > x[f].ar)
        {
            if ((time[e] + x[f].ser - x[f].exp) > 0)
            {
                t[f] = t[e] + (time[e] - x[f].ar)*x[f].wf + (time[e] + x[f].ser - x[f].exp)*x[f].df;
            }
            else
            {
                t[f] = t[e] + (time[e] - x[f].ar)*x[f].wf;
            }
            time[f] = time[e] + x[f].ser;
        }
        else
        {
            t[f] = t[e] + 0;
            time[f] = x[f].ar + x[f].ser;
        }
        if (t[f] < min)
        {
            for (g = 0; g < n; g++)
            {
                functionD(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, t, time, min, arr, count);
            }
        }
    }
}

void functionF(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, *t, *time, *min, *arr, *count) {
    if (e != d && e != c && e != b && e != a)
    {
        time[e] = 0;
        if (time[d] > x[e].ar)
        {
            if ((time[d] + x[e].ser - x[e].exp) > 0)
            {
                t[e] = t[d] + (time[d] - x[e].ar)*x[e].wf + (time[d] + x[e].ser - x[e].exp)*x[e].df;
            }
            else
            {
                t[e] = t[d] + (time[d] - x[e].ar)*x[e].wf;
            }
            time[e] = time[d] + x[e].ser;
        }
        else
        {
            t[e] = t[d] + 0;
            time[e] = x[e].ar + x[e].ser;
        }
        if (t[e] < min)
        {
            for (f = 0; f < n; f++)
            {
                functionE(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, t, time, min, arr, count);
            }
        }
    }
}

void functionG(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, *t, *time, *min, *arr, *count) {
    if (d != c && d != b && d != a)
    {
        time[d] = 0;
        if (time[c] > x[d].ar)
        {
            if ((time[c] + x[d].ser - x[d].exp) > 0)
            {
                t[d] = t[c] + (time[c] - x[d].ar)*x[d].wf + (time[c] + x[d].ser - x[d].exp)*x[d].df;
            }
            else
            {
                t[d] = t[c] + (time[c] - x[d].ar)*x[d].wf;
            }
            time[d] = time[c] + x[d].ser;
        }
        else
        {
            t[d] = t[c] + 0;
            time[d] = x[d].ar + x[d].ser;
        }
        if (t[d] < min)
        {
            for (e = 0; e < n; e++)
            {
                functionF(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, t, time, min, arr, count);
            }
        }
    }
}

void functionH(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, *t, *time, *min, *arr, *count) {
    if (c != b && c != a)
    {
        time[c] = 0;
        if (time[b] > x[c].ar)
        {
            if ((time[b] + x[c].ser - x[c].exp) > 0)
            {
                t[c] = t[b] + (time[b] - x[c].ar)*x[c].wf + (time[b] + x[c].ser - x[c].exp)*x[c].df;
            }
            else
            {
                t[c] = t[b] + (time[b] - x[c].ar)*x[c].wf;
            }
            time[c] = time[b] + x[c].ser;
        }
        else
        {
            t[c] = t[b] + 0;
            time[c] = x[c].ar + x[c].ser;
        }
        if (t[c] < min)
        {
            for (d = 0; d < n; d++)
            {
                functionG(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, t, time, min, arr, count);
            }
        }
    }
}

void functionI(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, *t, *time, *min, *arr, *count) {
    if (b != a)/*One vessel can be served only once.*/
    {
        time[b] = 0;
        if (time[a] > x[b].ar)/*If vessel arrived during service time of the previous one*/
        {
            if ((time[a] + x[b].ser - x[b].exp) > 0)/*If the service of current vessel ends after the due time.*/
            {
                t[b] = t[a] + (time[a] - x[b].ar)*x[b].wf + (time[a] + x[b].ser - x[b].exp)*x[b].df;
            }
            else/*If the service ends before the due time.*/
            {
                t[b] = t[a] + (time[a] - x[b].ar)*x[b].wf;
            }
            time[b] = time[a] + x[b].ser;/*Update time. The time when the service of current vessel ends.*/
        }
        else/*If vessel arrives after the service time of the previous one.*/
        {
            t[b] = t[a] + 0;/*No penalty or waiting cost.*/
            time[b] = x[b].ar + x[b].ser;/*Update time. Current vessel arrival time + its service time.*/
        }
        if (t[b] < min)/*Check if current cost is smaller than found minimum cost. If yes, continue. If not, go to the start of the loop. LOOP END.*/
        {
            for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
            {
                functionH(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, t, time, min, arr, count);
            }
        }
    }
}

void main()
{

FILE *f1;
int n = 10;/*The number of vessels*/
int arr[10];
int count = 0, s = 1;
int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j;
int t[10];
int min;
int time[10];


struct vessel{
    int name;/*the name of the vessel*/
    int ar; /*arrival time*/
    int ser; /*service time*/
    int exp; /*due time*/
    int df; /*delay factor*/
    int wf; /*waiting factor*/
};
struct vessel x[10]; /* where number means the total number of vessels arriving*/

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    s = s*(n-i) ;
}
printf("S is %d\n", s);/*The number of possible sequences. (n-1)! */


f1 = fopen("sample1.txt", "r");/*Read data from file*/
if (f1 == NULL){
    printf("Can not open the file\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    fscanf(f1, "%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", &x[i].name, &x[i].ar, &x[i].ser, &x[i].exp, &x[i].df, &x[i].wf);
    arr[i] = x[i].name;
}

/*f2 = fopen("results.txt", "w");*/

min = 9999999999;/*Set it to be big.*/

for (a = 0; a < n; a++)/*First step. Set time and cost.*/
{
    t[a] = 0;/*As first vessel comes and goes, there are no penalt or waiting cost.*/
    time[a] = x[a].ar + x[a].ser;/*The time vessel arrives + the service time.*/
    for (b = 0; b < n; b++)/*LOOP START.*/
    {
        functionI(j, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x, t, time, min, arr, count);
    }
}

printf("Final sequence is: ");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
}
printf("\nFinal count is %d\n", count);
printf("Final cost is %d\n", min);


getch();
return 0;
}
```